# How to plot a gg barplot for a single factor column?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

[image]

My data frame has 621 rows and each column describes something about it. I'm trying to do a exploratory data analysis where I plot out all the data into a bar plot.

I have a factor column called phenotype, which has 86 levels which describe the main condition in my cohort. I want to plot this out as 86 separate bar plots, each with the total number of people who have that condition on `ggplot`.

I've attached a screenshot of my data below, I basically want the x axis to have the condition name like the 'Bardet-Biedl Syndrome', 'Classic Ehlers Danlos Syndrome' etc and on the y axis the number of people who have that condition, such as 3,4,5 as displayed below etc. I got the below data by basically doing

```
table(data.frame$Phenotype)
```

I'm using the below code to generate my ggplot

```
ggplot (tiering, aes(x = Phenotype, y = count(tiering$Phenotype))) + 
  theme bw() + 
  geom bar(stat = "identity")
```

I'm sure the answer is out there, but I've looked on the R help websites and I can't seem to figure this out, so would be very grateful for the help.

EDIT: I got to a marplot with the help of the below code, just trying to reorder the bar/columns in [decreasing order and tried this method](https://www.statology.org/ggplot-order-x-axis/) but it hasn't worked. Would anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Try copy / pasting this exact code: `ggplot(as.data.frame(table(tiering$Phenotype)), aes(Var1, Freq)) + geom_col()`

Comment: Thank you, is there a way I can order it by the one with the most frequency first and the next? Sorry should I modify the question?